# Multiline textbox have bulk data, resulting in application hangs while resizing window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-3.5

In my WPF application WPF multiple `TextBox` is having very large data populated from a WCF service. Now when I try to Select All text of that `TextBox` or resize the parent Window of that `TextBox` the application hangs completely for 1-2 minutes. Is there any specific workaround for this?

Comment: although in 4.0 framework it is working a lot better but not fully

Comment: try with isAsync = true in binding context

Comment: @Jodha I think isAsync is in 4.0

Comment: As far as i know there is none. The text controls work pretty badly in WPF. You can't use them for that much text. Only option is to build your own textcontrol, which works with streaming and virtualization or use an existing control. [AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor) seems to handle all these stuff quite nicely.

Comment: Avalon needs .net 4.0 while my project is in .net 3.5

Comment: Does the text have lines?  One option is to break the text into lines and display it is ListBox with textblocks (lighter than textbox) as ti have vitualization.   For copy you would need to have a button to load the text in the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

A related question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048179/poor-textbox-performance-with-wrapping-on-and-large-amounts-of-data/11053170#11053170)

Try turning off TextWrapping in xaml or handling the windowResizeStart event to disable wrapping until the resize is complete.